# Python: My while loop keeps appending the first color in the list

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, euclidean-distance, ppm

My while loop does not execute through correctly. It will go through and increment i how it is supposed to, but it does not increment i outside of the loop. This means it keeps appending the same rgb pixel color pairs ~4000 times. Any thoughts?

Input file example: ( I skip first three rows because that is file type, photo dimensions, # or colors. The rest are r,g,b pixel data. Every 3 rows is one pixel in the order of r,g,b)

```
P3
200 200
255
192
48
64
216
52
180
252
8
176
212
96
4
152
108
108
20
248
64
80
140
132
```

My Code:

```
import math

with open('Ocean.ppm','r') as f:
    output = f.read().split("\n")
i = 0
r_point = 3 + i
g_point = 4 + i
b_point = 5 + i

resolution = []
resolution.append(output[1].split(" "))
file_size = resolution[0]
file_size = int(file_size[0]) * int(file_size[1])
file_size = int(file_size*3)
print(file_size)

pixel_list = []
pixel_list.append(str(output[0]))
pixel_list.append(str(output[1]))
pixel_list.append(str(output[2]))

while file_size >= i:
    red   = math.sqrt((int(output[r_point])-255)**2 + (int(output[g_point]) - 0)**2 + (int(output[b_point])-0)**2)
    green = math.sqrt((int(output[r_point])-0)**2 + (int(output[g_point]) - 255)**2 + (int(output[b_point])-0)**2)
    blue  = math.sqrt((int(output[r_point])-0)**2 + (int(output[g_point]) - 0)**2 + (int(output[b_point])-255)**2)
    white = math.sqrt((int(output[r_point])-0)**2 + (int(output[g_point]) - 0)**2 + (int(output[b_point])-0)**2)
    black = math.sqrt((int(output[r_point])-255)**2 + (int(output[g_point]) - 255)**2 + (int(output[b_point])-255)**2)

    L = [red, green, blue, white, black]
    idx = min(range(len(L)), key=L.__getitem__)

    if idx == 0:
        # red
        pixel_list.append('255')
        pixel_list.append('0')
        pixel_list.append('0')
        i += 3

    elif idx == 1:
        # green
        pixel_list.append('0')
        pixel_list.append('255')
        pixel_list.append('0')
        i += 3


    elif idx == 2:
        # blue
        pixel_list.append('0')
        pixel_list.append('0')
        pixel_list.append('255')
        i += 3


    elif idx == 3:
        # white
        pixel_list.append('0')
        pixel_list.append('0')
        pixel_list.append('0')
        i += 3


    elif idx == 4:
        # black
        pixel_list.append('255')
        pixel_list.append('255')
        pixel_list.append('255')
        i += 3



f = open('myfile.ppm','w')
for line in pixel_list:
    f.write(line + "\n")
```

Comment: I haven't tested anything. But maybe put incrementing i outside the if statement at the very end instead of in each if. Also try printing your idx value to see if it is between 0 and 4

Comment: There are a few peculiar statements in the code. .. it's rather complicated to understand what it does and why.  No input file format given

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to move the following to **inside** the loop:

```
r_point = 3 + i
g_point = 4 + i
b_point = 5 + i
```

With that it will update the index to your lists.